# Vector space over finite field: finding the plane perpendicular the vector $(1,1,1)$

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

For some 3 dimensional vector space over a finite field $F_{p^k}$ how can I determine (and visualise) the elements which are in a plane which is perpendicular to the vector $(1, 1, 1)$? For an $n$ dimensional vector space over $F_{p^k}$ how can I determine/visualise the points which are in the $n-1$ dimensional space perpendicular to the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$?

In the case of a 2 dimensional vector space the line perpendicular to the unit vector $(1,1)$ which passes through the point $(1,1)$ can be visualised as a diagonal line from $(0, p^k - 1)$ to $(p^k - 1, 0)$ but I'm struggling to visualise even the 3 dimensional case.

Comment: What is THE unit vector? And for which norm?

Comment: Oops. I mean the vector $(1, 1,\dots, 1)$, which is not a unit vector.

Comment: Well, such a hyperplane has equation $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=0$. What else can you say?

Comment: Is this plane really perpendicular to the vector? What if $n = p^k$ then $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = 0$ mod $p^k$ contains both the points $(0,0,\dots,0)$ and $(1,1,\dots, 1)$. It is meant to be perpendicular to the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ yet it contains two points where line between them is parallel to the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: Actually, you have to define an inner product  on your vector space.

Comment: This may be a very hopeful thought but Is there a 'natural' inner product on vector spaces over finite fields?

I was imagining vectors being orthogonal when they are orthogonal in the vector space with same dimension over the reals but I suppose there may not be an inner product which is consistent with that.

Comment: No. There is nothing like an inner product over a finite field. A fundamental problem is that we have no way of splitting the elements of a finite field into positive and negative elements. Because you get to $-1$ by adding together sufficiently many $+1$s. There are non-degenerate symmetric bililnear forms though, and sometimes they work as nice substitutes. But, as you observed, a vector may then be "orthogonal" to itself. That is inevitable.

Comment: Mind you, unless $p=3$ the subspace spanned by $(1,1,1)$ is not orthogonal to itself, so you get the usual decomposition into a sum of 1D and 2D subspaces orthgonal to each other.

Comment: But, *visualizing* this is taxing. The field $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ is itself already a $k$-dimensional vector space over the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$, and cannot be easily *visualized* as a line.

Comment: By the way. Chris, are you sure you are not confusing arithmetic modulo $p^k$ and the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$? Integers modulo $p^k$ do not form a field because every multiple of $p$ is a zero divisor. You get the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ as the quotient ring of polynomials
$$\Bbb{F}_{p^k}=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle,$$ where the generator of that ideal, $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$, is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$.

Comment: You are right, I have been confusing arithmetic module $p^k$ and the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$.

So in general a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of dimension $k$ which is not a multiple of $p$ will be such that the subspace $x_1 + ... + x_k = 0$ isn't orthogonal to itself. I think I have my answer for visualising in this case - the points in $x_1 + ... + x_k = 0$ are the points which are in $x_1 + ... + x_k = 0$, $x_1 + ... + x_k = p$, $x_1 + ... + x_k = p * 2$, ..., $x_1 + ... + x_k = p*(n-1)$ in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For example I made this plot for $\mathbb{F}_5^3$, which is the intersection of the planes $x_1 + ... + x_k = 0$, $x_1 + ... + x_k = 5$, $x_1 + ... + x_k = 10$ with $\mathbb{F}_5^3$.
https://technology.cpm.org/general/3dgraph/?graph3ddata=____bHw7kw7kw7kIx1Yxmuw7kJx1Yw7kxmuKx1YxBEx1YLx1Yx1YxBEMx1YxQOxQOHxQOxBEw7kIxQOw7kxBEJxQOxmuxmuKxQOx1YxQOLxQOxQOx1YMxBExQOw7kHxBEw7kxQOIxBExBExmuJxBExmuxBEKxBEx1Yx1YLxmux1Yw7kMxmuw7kx1YHxmuxQOxmuIxmuxmuxQOJxmuxBExBEKw7kx1YxmuLw7kxmux1YMw7kxQOxBEHw7kxBExQO